# Get days left till end of the month with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to display or hide a link depending on whether there are less than 2 weeks left in the month, using moment.js, but I'm not sure the correct way to go about it.

Currently I have...

```
if (moment().endOf('month')<=(13, 'days'))
{
    //do link stuff here
}
```

...but I don't think that's the correct way of doing it. It certainly isn't doing anything anyway. Could anyone give me any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var a = moment().endOf('month');
var b = moment();

if(a.diff(b, 'days') <= 13)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a plain javascript version, I've wrote this function:

```
function getMonthDaysLeft(){
    date = new Date();
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate() - date.getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help.

```
const d = moment();
const currentDay = d.get("date");
const daysInMonth = d.daysInMonth();
const remainingDays = daysInMonth - currentDay;

console.log(remainingDays <= 13)
```